# Dynamicaly set class instance variable in java

Tags: java

Hi I am working on a project which has a variable which is an instance of the class. The problem is that depending on which option the user picks the instance variable can be on of the classes.

How can I assign a variable to an instance of a class when it can be 1 class or another class?

For example,

```
//I don't know if this variable is going to be of type class 1 or class 2 
//at this point any suggestions?

Class1 var1;

if(x == true)
{
  var1 = new Class1
}
else
{
  var1 = new Class2
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should define some interface which both `Class1` and `Class2` implement.  So, for example, your `Class1` definition might look like this:

```
public class Class1 implements MyInterface {
    // ...
}
```

One nice way to handle your original question is to use a factory pattern:

```
public class ClassFactory {
    public static MyInterface getClass(boolean type) {
        if (x) {
            return new Class1();
        }
        else {
            return new Class2();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, give some boolean input, you may obtain the correct instance using:

```
boolean b = true;
MyInterface correctClass = ClassFactory.MyInterface(b);
```

The factory pattern is one of many *design patterns* which are available to structure your code in a good way, and make problems like this easier to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can defined your variable as

```
Object var1;
if(x == true)
{
     var1 = new Class1();
}
else
{
    var1 = new Class2();
}
```

and then cast it later on when needed

```
if(var1 instanceof Class1){
    Class1 v = (Class1)var1;
    // ...
} else if(var1 instanceof Class2){
    Class2 v = (Class2)var1;
    // ...
}
```

but usually this is a sign of a questionable code design.

Comment: *but usually this is a sign of a questionable code design.* - so why do it?